# Flexdashboard gauge labels are cut off in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I have built an app that is heavily dependent on gauges to track progress. There was an issue with the label not updating with new input so I have updated my version of flexdashboard to the development version: `remotes::install_github("rstudio/flexdashboard")`.

However, now I have done this the labels of all my gauges are cut off if they are more than one line. See the screenshot below:

[image]

I have tried to change the height/width of the column, div and svg using css, but I do not want the gauges larger and that is the only solution that has worked.

I've included below a reprex:

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/flexdashboard")
library(shiny)
library(flexdashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(12, gaugeOutput("gauge1")),
  column(12, gaugeOutput("gauge2"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$gauge1 <- renderGauge({
    gauge(15, min=0, max=100, label="Line 1\n Line2")
  })
  
  output$gauge2 <- renderGauge({
    gauge(25, min=0, max=100, label="Line 1\n Line2")
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: On my machine the two lines are shown properly. Can't reproduce the shown issue!

Comment: @TarJae did you try also with the development version? Using ```remotes::install_github("rstudio/flexdashboard")```.

Comment: I use flexdashboard 0.5.2

Comment: Worked properly on my machine too.

Comment: @lz100 It's with the dev version? TarJae was not using the correct version in the end. Anyways I just built a workaround to generate text near the gauges.

Comment: I also have 0.5.2

Comment: @lz100 it must be 0.5.2.900

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed as seen here: https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/388